# Defining Multiple API Routes in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have defined an API route in Laravel like this

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
    Route::resource('getdealsbymerchant/{merchant_url_text}', 'dealsController@index');
});
```

This route is working fine and returning me a response. I want to add another route like this in the group

```
Route::resource('getsimilarmerchants/{merchant_id}', 'similarmerchantsController@index');
```

However, when I add this and try to hit

```
http://localhost/api/getsimilarmerchants/123
```

it is giving me an error

```
Route pattern "/api/getdealsbymerchant/{merchant_url_text}/{{merchant_url_text}}" cannot reference variable name "merchant_url_text" more than once.
```

Any help on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a resource controller pointed to a method?
It should be

```
Route::resource('getdealsbymerchant', 'dealsController');
```

Similarly define the second resource too. Read more here : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

If you just want a get/post route, define as follows

```
Route::get('getdealsbymerchant/{merchant_url_text}', 'dealsController@index');
```

Comment: Changed them to Route::resource('getdealsbymerchant/{merchant_url_text}', 'dealsController');
    Route::resource('getsimilarmerchants/{merchant_id}', 'similarmerchantsController'); in the API group route. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I don't think you can pass a parameter to the "resource" controller, like you have done with `{merchant_url_text}`

Comment: It does work that way. Its working for my first route. I can access the merchant_url_text in my dealsController index function. Just not working for second route.

Comment: Its working for my first route. I can access the merchant_url_text in my dealsController index function. Just not working for second route. But the next route is not working. How do I pass parameter to my API call if I cannot do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was doing it wrong.

Defined 2 routes like this and was able to resolve the issue.

```
Route::get('api/getsimilarmerchants/{merchant_id}', ['uses' => 'similarmerchantsController@index']);
Route::get('api/getdealsbymerchant/{merchant_url_text}', ['uses' => 'dealsController@index']);
```